# Экспорт таблицы из pandas в Google Bigquery

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe, bigquery

Подскажите как экспортировать таблицу из Pandas в Google Bigquery?
Пробовал через pandas gbq, но выдает ошибку:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py:196: FutureWarning: private_key is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.Use the credentials argument instead. See https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html for examples on using the credentials argument with service account keys.
  pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
5Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/vd/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.2/scratches/scratch_40.py", line 25, in <module>
    data_frame.to_gbq('my_dataset.my_table', project_id=1, if_exists='fail', private_key='/Users/daniilorlov/Downloads/hseparser-261610-e5e26181b8be.json')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1510, in to_gbq
    gbq.to_gbq(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 196, in to_gbq
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(
  File "/Users/daniilorlov/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 1206, in to_gbq
    connector = GbqConnector(
  File "/Users/daniilorlov/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 372, in __init__
    self.client = self.get_client()
  File "/Users/daniilorlov/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 420, in get_client
    return bigquery.Client(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 174, in __init__
    super(Client, self).__init__(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 226, in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 187, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Project must be a string.")
ValueError: Project must be a string.
```

Вот мой код:

```
from pandas.compat._optional import import_optional_dependency
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = "https://ege.hse.ru/rating/2019/81031971/all/?rlist=&ptype=0&vuz-abiturients-budget-order=ge&vuz-abiturients-budget-val=10"
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.find("table", {"id": "transparence_t"})

data_frame = pd.read_html(str(tbl))[0]
data_frame.columns=['Вуз','Качество приема на основании среднего балла ЕГЭ зачисленных на бюджетные места 2019','Рост/ падение 2019-2018','Количество студентов, зачисленных на бюджетные места','Из них: без экзаменов','Ср.балл рассчитан с вычетом баллов за И.Д.?']
data_frame.to_gbq('my_dataset.my_table', project_id=1, if_exists='fail', private_key='/Users/daniilorlov/Downloads/hseparser-261610-e5e26181b8be.json')
```

Comment: Так сложно посмотреть ответ программы? **`Project must be a string`** – ну так сделайте строку, а не `project_id=1`!

Comment: Сделал, но все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Очевидно, то была далеко не единственная ошибка в этом коде ‍♀️ Разбирайте их и решайте по возможности самостоятельно. Здесь не любят решать то, с чем можно справиться самостоятельно за несколько минут с гуглом.